# Why are new content items created in the content editor populated with data not in the __Standard Values of the template in Sitecore 7.2?

Tags: content-editor, templates

In Sitecore 7.2 I am having an issue in the Content Editor where when I add a new item based off of a template that has no __Standard Values the fields are being populated with data from an unknown source.

[image]

This is a very simple image of what is happening but as you can see the Quantity field has a value of "1" upon creation of the item but there is no Quantity default value set on the __Standard Values template.

Comment: Is this happening on all your templates or just this one that the test item is based off of? Also field type is the "Quantity" field set as?

Comment: Do you have a branch template that the item could be based on?  The value could be set there.

Comment: Just curious. Can you look at the insert options and make sure what is being inserted is not a branch template? It is possible to default from a branch template. Under templates\branches.

Comment: PatrickBarron this is only happening for this specific template and Quantity is a Single-Line Text field. RReiley and Lyle Jordan Thanks for the tip. I looked under Branches and did not see anything in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find out how these fields were getting their values defaulted. There was custom code written in our solution that hooked into the OnItemCreated event. The code was checking for this specific template and setting the item fields based on some custom logic.

[It was something similar to this.](https://sitecorecommerce.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/sitecore-itemcreated-event/)

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for the update. Glad you found a solution.